# prop('checked', true) sets value only visually, but not passed to server on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a checkbox list ([checkgroup]) in the form, and I have the leading "check/uncheck all" checkbox ([checkgroup].checkall-responsive). Yet this one is not only facade/interface focused, but is meant to send the value to the server, indicating either ALL or NOT ALL elements in the list have been checked.

Thus, I have simple JQuery behaviour applied to all checkbox list elements and the leading "check all" element, so that if all of the list elements are checked, the leading checkbox gets checked automatically.

And it does get checked fine visually, but when I submit the form, the value does not arrive. In other words, the value gets passed to the server only when I check the leading checkbox manually, but not via checking all the checkboxes in the list.

Confirmed on FF and Safari on MacOS. Tried prop and attr: same result. Here is the snippet:

```
$("input[checkgroup]").live("click",function () {
        var group=$(this).attr("checkgroup");
        //alert(group);
        if ($(this).hasClass("checkall-responsive")) {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("input[checkgroup="+group+"]").not(".checkall-responsive").prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $("input[checkgroup="+group+"]").not(".checkall-responsive").prop('checked', false);
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($("input[checkgroup="+group+"]").not(".checkall-responsive").length==$("input[checkgroup="+group+"]:checked").not(".checkall-responsive").length) {
                $("input[checkgroup="+group+"].checkall-responsive").prop('checked', true);
                //alert($("input[type=checkbox].checkall-responsive").length);
            }
            else {
                $("input[checkgroup="+group+"].checkall-responsive").prop('checked', false);
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Do the checkbox `<input>`s have a name attribute?

Comment: yes, they sure do, all of them